# Use value from void in onCreate inputfilter

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, diskspace, input-filter

I'm working on an app which generates swap space on the `/cache` partition of Android devices. It can already calculate the maximum size of the swap, but the maximum amount one can enter is still static.

For the `EditText` `InputFilter` I use this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    ... 
    final EditText mb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mb.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "120")});
    ...
}
```

And my void is this:

```
// Check Disk Space and display
void readSpace(){
    execCommandLine("mount -o rw,remount /cache");
    File spacechecker = new File("/cache");
    long totalSpace = spacechecker.getTotalSpace();
    long usableSpace = spacechecker.getUsableSpace();

    TextView tsp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AmmountTotal);
    tsp.setText(totalSpace /1024 /1024 + " MB");

    TextView usp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AmmountAvailable);
    usp.setText(usableSpace /1024 /1024 + " MB");

    TextView rsp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AmmountRecommended);
    rsp.setText(usableSpace /1024 /1024 -20 + " MB");
}
```

How can I get the 120 to be the value of `long usableSpace` in MB?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to change the upper limit of your TextView, yes?

```
  mb.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", Long.toString(usableSpace / 1024 / 1024))});
```

Comment: Yeah, you understood that right, but every time I try to use usableSpace in my onCreate method, Eclipse tells me that it cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Do it in your readSpace method.  Call findViewById again and then set it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! now I got it right! The finished, working, code is:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
         ...
         readSpace();
         ... 
         final EditText mb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         ...
}
```

And:

```
// Check Disk Space and display
void readSpace(){
    execCommandLine("mount -o rw,remount /cache");
    File spacechecker = new File("/cache");
    long totalSpace = spacechecker.getTotalSpace();
    long usableSpace = spacechecker.getUsableSpace();

    TextView tsp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AmmountTotal);
    tsp.setText(totalSpace /1024 /1024 + " MB");

    TextView usp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AmmountAvailable);
    usp.setText(usableSpace /1024 /1024 + " MB");

    TextView rsp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AmmountRecommended);
    rsp.setText(usableSpace /1024 /1024 -20 + " MB");

    EditText mb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mb.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", Long.toString(usableSpace /1024 /1024))});

}
```